# Django 1.4 says "No database fixture specified. Please provide the path of at least one fixture in the command line."

Tags: django, unit-testing, fixtures

while all tests complete without errors and fixtures are actually loaded. Is it Django 1.4 issue?

Please note that only some of the applications provoke this error message (there is no conceptual difference between the applications' unit tests and their corresponding fixtures).

**Update 1:** the *fasttest.py* content:

```
DATABASES = {'default':
  {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': ':memory:',
  }
}

~/django_project$ ./manage.py test appname --traceback --settings=fasttest
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.....................No database fixture specified. Please provide the path of at least one fixture in the command line.
 .
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 22 tests in 8.426s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

**Update 2:** obviously the comments, although I am thankful for the tries, are only shots in the dark.
The database does not matter, neither SQLite3, nor Postgres testing DBs solve the problem.

Comment: We really need a lot more detail. Can you copy the entire stack trace into the question? It would also be good to see the database section of your settings.py file.

Comment: If I remember well you need to specify the path for the db if you're going to use sqlite3 as DB support. This used to be a commented requirement in Django 1.3.1. I can't say for sure its the same for 1.4, but you can try.

Comment: Actually, I think the colons are the problem with the DB. Try taking them out and see if it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had this same issue with test fixtures that had worked fine under 1.4.

For me, I had one test case where I wasn't using a fixture, and so I was setting fixtures to an empty set like this:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = []
```

When I commented out that line, the error went away:

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):
#    fixtures = []
```

Comment: Django's `TestCase._fixture_setup()` only checks `hasattr('fixtures')` rather than checking for content, then calls loaddata which is where the complaint is coming from. You can avoid both the error message and the actual fixture loading by setting something bogus, since loaddata doesn't complain about that: `fixtures = ['BOGUS']`